# List.add() doesn't work when called by a method from another class

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter/dart and trying to create a learning project.
I needed a list which I first added in `main.dart` but then separated it with another class.
I've 3 files now

1. `main.dart`
2. `icon.dart`
3. `mid.dart`

`main.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:test_project/icon.dart';
import 'mid.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade900,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
            child: Testing(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Testing extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestingState createState() => _TestingState();
}

class _TestingState extends State<Testing> {
  MyIcons myIcons = MyIcons();
  Mid mid = Mid();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          flex: 2,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: myIcons.icon1,
                ),
                Row(
                  children: myIcons.icon2,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                child: FlatButton(
                  color: Colors.teal,
                  child: Text(
                    'Add Check Icon',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      myIcons.icon1.add(Icon(
                        Icons.check,
                        color: Colors.green,
                      ));
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                child: FlatButton(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: Text(
                    'Add Cross Icon',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      mid.addIcon();
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

`icon.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyIcons {
  List<Icon> icon1 = [];
  List<Icon> icon2 = [];
}
```

and
`mid.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'icon.dart';
//import 'main.dart';

class Mid {
  MyIcons myIcons = MyIcons();

  void addIcon() {
    myIcons.icon2.add(Icon(
      Icons.close,
      color: Colors.red,
    ));
  }
}
```

I can add `check icons` successfully when by pressing the first button which directly calls the object of `icon.dart` file and adds the icons into list
But can't add `cross icons` when I call the method `addIcon()` from `mid.dart`.

here is the layout of the app:

[App Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jC2za.jpg)

Comment: You are not using the `mid` field anywhere, so your second button changes an object that is not used to do anything with.

Comment: @spkersten got that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Mid class has it's own myIcons, which is a separate instance than the one in _TestingState.

To use only one set of myIcons, you don't need to instantiate another one in _TestingState, because the Mid() instantiation already instantiates its own MyIcon. (if that makes sense)

Here's how I would change the _TestingState class in main.dart, no need to change anything else.

```
// ... Main.dart file 

class _TestingState extends State<Testing> {
  Mid mid = Mid();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          flex: 2,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: mid.myIcons.icon1,
                ),
                Row(
                  children: mid.myIcons.icon2,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                child: FlatButton(
                  color: Colors.teal,
                  child: Text(
                    'Add Check Icon',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      mid.myIcons.icon1.add(Icon(
                        Icons.check,
                        color: Colors.green,
                      ));
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                child: FlatButton(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: Text(
                    'Add Cross Icon',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      mid.addIcon();
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Notice how I removed the myIcons instantiation in _TestingState, and accessed the myIcons in mid instead. so mid.addIcon() adds to icon2, whereas mid.myIcons.icon1.add() will add to icon1.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. But I'm unable to understand why it stops working when we have instantiated icon class twice, once in mid and once in main? how do both instantiations conflict with each other and stop working?

Comment: It doesn't conflict with each other. Since they are separate instantiations, when you added to icon2 in mid, it doesn't reflect what you see because you only showed the icon2 from myIcons in TestingState rather than in Mid. Having mid.myIcons means I'm accessing the myIcons inside mid, but if you just put myIcons, you're referring to the one you instantiated in TestingState rather than the one in mid. Perhaps revise some Object Orientated Programming fundamentals, you may have misunderstood some concepts.